# I added the button of javascript but not working

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```html
<p id="para1">Hi</p>
<button onclick="style()">Submit</button>

<script>
function style(){
  var text= document.getElementById("para1").style.color="green";
}
</script>
```

I added html code using javascript. All the headings and divs are working fine except the Button. The Button is not added or may be not working for some reasons. Please check my code give some suggestions. When I used the same code as html it worked fine.

Comment: kindly post the code where you add html using js

Comment: Please post your solution as the answer

Comment: Delete "var text=" 
Just write this codes
document.getElementById("para1").style.color="green";

Answer (score 0):

`style` has a special meaning in JavaScript, use some other name as the name of your function:

```html
<p id="para1">Hi</p>
<button onclick="elementStyle()">Submit</button>

<script>
  function elementStyle(){
    document.getElementById("para1").style.color="green";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to add a class to the element, that should be styled. Then you are very flexible in styling it:

```html
<p id="para1">Hi</p>
<button onclick="stylePara1()">Submit</button>

<style>
  .green-text {
    color: green
  }
</style>

<script>
  function stylePara1(){
    document.querySelector('#para1').classList.add('green-text');
  }
</script>
```

Or use inline syntax:

```html
<p id="para1">Hi</p>
<button onclick="document.querySelector('#para1').classList.add('green-text')">Submit</button>

<style>
  .green-text {
    color: green
  }
</style>
```